# Lookup field Join not working

Tags: linq

I am new to sharepoint and i am using Linq to Sharepoint in my project.
I have two Lists in TestSite.
Details are as below

**Department**

DepartmentName  Single line of text
ManagerId       Person or Group
IsActive        Choice

**LeaveDetails**

EmployeeId        Person or Group
LeaveDescription  Multiple lines of text
ApprovalStatus    Choice
FromDate          Date and Time
ToDate            Date and Time
LeaveTypeId       Lookup
DepartmentId      Lookup
AppliedDate       Date and Time
AssignedTo        Person or Group
RejectionReason   Multiple lines of text

I am trying to join these two list.
By doing some googling on it i have created following Linq query but in the result it is showing Enumeration yielded no results.

the code is as below :

```
        SPList lstDept = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Department"];
        SPList lstLeaveDetails = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["LeaveDetails"];

        var v = from SPListItem ld in lstLeaveDetails.Items
                join SPListItem dept in lstDept.Items on ld["DepartmentId"] equals dept.Title
                select new
                {
                    Emp = ld.Title,
                    Id = dept.ID
                };
```

So, can any one tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: it is also Lookup field column and it is point to another list named LeaveType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This join will always have null result set since

```
ld["DepartmentId"] equals dept.Title
```

will always result in false because ld["DepartmentId"] will never equal to dept.Title  since they are of different types

You must join on fields of the same type
I even do not see in your Department list a field "Title" but I presume it is there as "Single line of text" while "DepartmentId" is int (Number, Number of decimal places: 0)

You should have probably written, as minimum:

```
ld["DepartmentId"] equals dept.Id
```

instead of

```
ld["DepartmentId"] equals dept.Title
```

**Update2:**
If the DepartmentId is lookup to field DepartmentName then write:

```
ld["DepartmentId"] equals dept.DepartmentName
```

instead

Comment: can you please give me the suggestion to correct it?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: but DepartmentId is the lookup column linked with the field Title....and Title is a renamed to DepartmentName

Comment: Updated by Update2. You might probably not have Title field after its renaming if you have not created a new one with such name